# Why is my Angular routing module not working with parameters?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, apache, router

I have the following routing-module:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },\
  { path: 'x', component: xComponent},
  { path: 'x-d/:mid', component: xdComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

When I go in the browser directly into `mywebsite/x` it works perfectly, however, if I go to `mywebsite/x-d/5` (any id should work here) it gets me an error 404.

I already configured my apache to fallback to `index.html` so Angular handles everything in the front end, however, a route with a parameter is not loading properly.

I included my `.htaccess` file with my fallback config below, it's the standard on Angular Documentation for Apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to add `pathMatch: "full"`

Comment: just to clarify - if id is e.g. ```123``` are you opening ```mywebsite/x-d/:123``` or ```mywebsite/x-d/123```? the later is correct

Comment: path: 'x-d/:mid, on that path, `:mid`is the variable and it should be replaced with the real value like 'abc'... That path does not accept special chars as you know due toh common path rule.

Comment: @capc0 yes, I open it by going to `x-d/x`. When I get to that path within the app (clicking an element that has a [routerlink] to the path) it works. However if I go to the exact same path directly from the address bar it gets me a 404.

Comment: @Lud didn't work.

Comment: @jquijano the quick fix would be adding useHath true `RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{useHash : true})` .

Comment: Thanks, @KamranKhatti I tried that, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I was running my build script with the following:

```
sudo ng build --prod --base-href ./
```

All I had to do was remove the dot, like this:

```
sudo ng build --prod --base-href /
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, your actual URL path should not contain *id* (or *mid* in your case) prepended with '**:**' . It should be e.g. `mywebsite/x-d/23`

Comment: Yes, I'm using it that way. The issue is using it as a direct link (not working) vs navigating to the route from the app (it works).

Comment: @jquijano Can you please provide a fiddle to have a closer look at the issue?